# FILE* in C++ not reading entire file

Tags: c++

I'm having a simple problem with my file, when i read in the FILE* and then print it out again after removing the punctuations it will only print out the bottom part of the file. The input i have is below at the bottom of this question. Question is : Is there any reason why its printing out only a section of the file?

Here's the code that reads in my FILE:

```
int currentLetter= 0;
        string word = "";
        FILE * input;

        input = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        if (input == NULL)
        {

            perror("Error opening file");
        }
        else{
            while(currentLetter != EOF){//Loop Through File
                do{// GETWORD
                    currentLetter = fgetc(input);
                    if(currentLetter == '?' || currentLetter == '<'|| currentLetter == '>'|| currentLetter == ':' ||currentLetter == '\"')
                        word += ' ';
                    if (isalpha(currentLetter) || isdigit(currentLetter) || currentLetter == '-' || currentLetter == '\'' )
                    {
                        word += tolower(currentLetter);
                    }

                }while(currentLetter != EOF && currentLetter != ' ' && currentLetter != '\n');

                if (word != " "  && !(word.find_first_of("0123456789") < word.length()))
                {
                    cout<< word << endl;
                    // insert(word); This will called the b

                }
                word = "";
            }
        }
```

Here is my input(quite big): 
A collection of five memorable texts.

> "I have, myself, full confidence that if all do their duty, if nothing
>   is neglected, and if the best arrangements are made, as they are being
>   made, we shall prove ourselves once again able to defend our Island
>   home, to ride out the storm of war, and to outlive the menace of
>   tyranny, if necessary for years, if necessary alone. At any rate, that
>   is what we are going to try to do. That is the resolve of His
>   Majesty's Government-every man of them. That is the will of Parliament
>   and the nation. The British Empire and the French Republic, linked
>   together in their cause and in their need, will defend to the death
>   their native soil, aiding each other like good comrades to the utmost
>   of their strength. Even though large tracts of Europe and many old and
>   famous States have fallen or may fall into the grip of the Gestapo and
>   all the odious apparatus of Nazi rule, we shall not flag or fail. We
>   shall go on to the end, we shall fight in France, we shall fight on
>   the seas and oceans, we shall fight with growing confidence and
>   growing strength in the air, we shall defend our Island, whatever the
>   cost may be, we shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the
>   landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we
>   shall fight in the hills; we shall never surrender, and even if, which
>   I do not for a moment believe, this Island or a large part of it were
>   subjugated and starving, then our Empire beyond the seas, armed and
>   guarded by the British Fleet, would carry on the struggle, until, in
>   God's good time, the New World, with all its power and might, steps
>   forth to the rescue and the liberation of the old." --Winston
>   Churchill, 1940
>
> "Fourscore and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this
>   continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated to the
>   proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a
>   great civil war, testing whether that nation or any nation so
>   conceived and so dedicated can long endure. We are met on a great
>   battlefield of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that
>   field as a final resting-place for those who here gave their lives
>   that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that
>   we should do this. But in a larger sense, we cannot dedicate, we
>   cannot consecrate, we cannot hallow this ground. The brave men, living
>   and dead who struggled here have consecrated it far above our poor
>   power to add or detract. The world will little note nor long remember
>   what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is
>   for us the living rather to be dedicated here to the unfinished work
>   which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is
>   rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before
>   us--that from these honoured dead we take increased devotion to that
>   cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion--that we
>   here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain, that
>   this nation under God shall have a new birth of freedom, and that
>   government of the people, by the people, for the people shall not
>   perish from the earth."  --Abraham Lincoln
>
> I say to you today, my friends, that in spite of the difficulties and
>   frustrations of the moment, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply
>   rooted in the American dream. I have a dream that one day this nation
>   will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: "We hold
>   these truths to be self-evident: that all men are created equal." I
>   have a dream that one day on the red hills of Georgia the sons of
>   former slaves and the sons of former slave owners will be able to sit
>   down together at a table of brotherhood. I have a dream that one day
>   even the state of Mississippi, a desert state, sweltering with the
>   heat of injustice and oppression, will be transformed into an oasis of
>   freedom and justice. I have a dream that my four children will one day
>   live in a nation where they will not be judged by the colour of their
>   skin but by the content of their character. I have a dream today. ---
>   Martin Luther King
>
> The Life and Death of Julies Caesar   by William Shakespeare
>
> SCENE II. A public place.
>
> Flourish. Enter CAESAR; ANTONY, for the course; CALPURNIA, PORTIA,
>   DECIUS BRUTUS, CICERO, BRUTUS, CASSIUS, and CASCA; a great crowd
>   following, among them a Soothsayer
>
> CAESAR  Let me have men about me that are fat; Sleek-headed men and
>   such as sleep o' nights: Yond Cassius has a lean and hungry look; He
>   thinks too much: such men are dangerous.
>
> ANTONY  Fear him not, Caesar; he's not dangerous; He is a noble Roman
>   and well given.
>
> CAESAR  Would he were fatter! But I fear him not: Yet if my name were
>   liable to fear, I do not know the man I should avoid So soon as that
>   spare Cassius. He reads much; He is a great observer and he looks
>   Quite through the deeds of men: he loves no plays, As thou dost,
>   Antony; he hears no music; Seldom he smiles, and smiles in such a sort
>   As if he mock'd himself and scorn'd his spirit That could be moved to
>   smile at any thing. Such men as he be never at heart's ease Whiles
>   they behold a greater than themselves, And therefore are they very
>   dangerous. I rather tell thee what is to be fear'd Than what I fear;
>   for always I am Caesar. Come on my right hand, for this ear is deaf,
>   And tell me truly what thou think'st of him.
>
> "Monty Python and the Holy Grail"
>
> Scene 25
>       HEAD KNIGHT:  Nee!
>         Nee!
>         Nee!
>         Nee!   ARTHUR:  Who are you?   HEAD KNIGHT:  We are the Knights Who Say... Nee!   ARTHUR:  No!  Not the Knights Who Say Nee!   HEAD
>   KNIGHT:  The same!   BEDEMIR:  Who are they?   HEAD KNIGHT:  We are
>   the keepers of the sacred words:  Nee, Pen, and
>         Nee-wom!   RANDOM:  Nee-wom!   ARTHUR:  Those who hear them seldom live to tell the tale!   HEAD KNIGHT:  The Knights Who Say Nee
>   demand a sacrifice!   ARTHUR:  Knights of Nee, we are but simple
>   travellers who seek the
>         enchanter who lives beyond these woods.   HEAD KNIGHT:  Nee!  Nee!  Nee!  Nee!   ARTHUR and PARTY:  Oh, ow!   HEAD KNIGHT:  We shall
>   say 'nee' again to you if you do not appease us.   ARTHUR:  Well, what
>   is it you want?   HEAD KNIGHT:  We want... a shrubbery!
>         [dramatic chord]   ARTHUR:  A what?   HEAD KNIGHT:  Nee!  Nee!   ARTHUR and PARTY:  Oh, ow!   ARTHUR:  Please, please!  No more!  We
>   shall find a shrubbery.   HEAD KNIGHT:  You must return here with a
>   shrubbery or else you will
>         never pass through this wood alive!   ARTHUR:  O Knights of Nee, you are just and fair, and we will return
>         with a shrubbery.   HEAD KNIGHT:  One that looks nice.   ARTHUR:  Of course.   HEAD KNIGHT:  And not too expensive.   ARTHUR:  Yes.
>   HEAD KNIGHTS:  Now... go!
>
> Scene 11
>
> GALAHAD:  Zoot!   DINGO:  No, I am Zoot's identical twin sister,
>   Dingo.   GALAHAD:  Oh, well, excuse me, I--   DINGO:  Where are you
>   going?   GALAHAD:  I seek the Grail!  I have seen it, here in this
>   castle!   DINGO:  No!  Oh, no!  Bad, bad Zoot!   GALAHAD:  What is it?
>   DINGO:  Oh, wicked, bad, naughty Zoot!  She has been setting alight
>         to our beacon, which, I just remembered, is grail-shaped.  It's not the
>         first time we've had this problem.   GALAHAD:  It's not the real Grail?   DINGO:  Oh, wicked, bad, naughty, evil Zoot!  Oh, she is a
>   naughty
>         person, and she must pay the penalty -- and here in Castle Anthrax, we
>         have but one punishment for setting alight the grail-shaped beacon.  You
>         must tie her down on a bed and spank her!   GIRLS:  A spanking!  A spanking!   DINGO:  You must spank her well.  And after you have
>   spanked her, you
>         may deal with her as you like.  And then, spank me.   VARIOUS GIRLS:  And spank me.
>         And me.
>         And me.   DINGO:  Yes, yes, you must give us all a good spanking!   GIRLS:  A spanking!  A spanking!
>
> Scene 35    ARTHUR:  There it is!  The Bridge of Death!   ROBIN:  Oh,
>   great.   KNIGHT:  Look!   ARTHUR:  There's the old man from Scene 24! 
>   BEDEMIR:  What is he doing here?   ARTHUR:  He is the keeper of the
>   Bridge of Death.  He asks each
>         traveller five questions--   KNIGHT:  Three questions.   ARTHUR:  Three questions.  He who answers the five questions--   KNIGHT:  Three
>   questions.   ARTHUR:  Three questions may cross in safety.   ROBIN: 
>   What if you get a question wrong?   ARTHUR:  Then you are cast into
>   the Gorge of Eternal Peril.   ROBIN:  Oh, I won't go.   KNIGHT:  Who's
>   going to answer the questions?   ARTHUR:  Sir Robin!   ROBIN:  Yes?
>   ARTHUR:  Brave Sir Robin, you go.   ROBIN:  Hey!  I've got a great
>   idea.  Why doesn't Launcelot go?   LAUNCELOT:  Yes, let me go, my
>   liege.  I will take him single-handed.
>         I shall make a feint to the north-east--   ARTHUR:  No, no, hang on, hang on, hang on!  Just answer the five
>         questions--   KNIGHT:  Three questions.   ARTHUR:  Three questions as best you can.  And we shall watch... and
>         pray.   LAUNCELOT:  I understand, my liege.   ARTHUR:  Good luck, brave Sir Launcelot.  God be with you.   KEEPER:  Stop!  Who
>   would cross the Bridge of Death must answer me
>         these questions three, 'ere the other side he see.   LAUNCELOT:  Ask me the questions, bridge-keeper.  I'm not afraid.   KEEPER:  What
>   is your name?   LAUNCELOT:  My name is Sir Launcelot of Camelot.
>   KEEPER:  What is your quest?   LAUNCELOT:  To seek the Holy Grail.
>   KEEPER:  What is your favourite colour?   LAUNCELOT:  Blue.   KEEPER: 
>   Right.  Off you go.   LAUNCELOT:  Oh, thank you.  Thank you very much.
>   ROBIN:  That's easy!   KEEPER:  Stop!  Who approaches the Bridge of
>   Death must answer me
>         these questions three, 'ere the other side he see.   ROBIN:  Ask me the questions, bridge-keeper.  I'm not afraid.   KEEPER:  What is
>   your name?   ROBIN:  Sir Robin of Camelot.   KEEPER:  What is your
>   quest?   ROBIN:  To seek the Holy Grail.   KEEPER:  What is the
>   capital of Assyria?   ROBIN:  I don't know that!  Auuuuuuuugh!
>   KEEPER:  Stop!  What is your name?   GALAHAD:  Sir Galahad of Camelot.
>   KEEPER:  What is your quest?   GALAHAD:  I seek the Holy Grail.
>   KEEPER:  What is your favourite colour?   GALAHAD:  Blue.  No yel-- 
>   Auuuuuuuugh!   KEEPER:  Heh heh.  Stop!  What is your name?   ARTHUR: 
>   It is Arthur, King of the Britons.   KEEPER:  What is your quest?
>   ARTHUR:  To seek the Holy Grail.   KEEPER:  What is the air-speed
>   velocity of an unladen swallow?   ARTHUR:  What do you mean?  An
>   African or European swallow?   KEEPER:  What?  I don't know that! 
>   Auuuuuuuugh!   BEDEMIR:  How do know so much about swallows?   ARTHUR:
>   Well, you have to know these things when you're a king you know.

my output:

[image]

Comment: Redirect output to another file and check what did you lost? Or you can increase the buffer size of your terminal. Currently some output of your program is scrolled up and lost forever.

Comment: Can that behaviour be reproduced with less text? Why don't you use C++ IOStreams? Further, you are using an input character before testing against EOF, which is wrong. Then, distill a minimal but complete example, your code can't be compiled and executed by anyone else.

Comment: Works fine for me, but I have a large buffer set for my consoles.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you aren't using C++ file I/O?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that text is scrolling off the top edge of your command window and being lost. Right-click the icon on the upper left edge of the title bar, open "Properties," and increase the window/screen buffer sizes to large amounts. Then try running again.

Or, run it at the command line and send the output to a file with the `>` character.

`assignment.exe > completeOutput.txt`

Answer (score 2):

The reason given my Stiles is perfectly correct. Just to try out I modified your code to open and write in another file. It printed the entire text.

```
int currentLetter = 0;
string word = "";
FILE * input;
FILE * result ;
int err = 0;
int errres = 0;
errres = fopen_s(&result, "result.txt", "a+");
err  = fopen_s(&input,"test.txt", "r");
if (err != 0)
{

    //perror("Error opening file");
    cout << "error" << endl;
}
else{
    while (currentLetter != EOF){//Loop Through File
        do{// GETWORD
            currentLetter = fgetc(input);
            if (currentLetter == '?' || currentLetter == '<' || currentLetter == '>' || currentLetter == ':' || currentLetter == '\"')
                word += ' ';
            if (isalpha(currentLetter) || isdigit(currentLetter) || currentLetter == '-' || currentLetter == '\'')
            {
                word += tolower(currentLetter);
            }

        } while (currentLetter != EOF && currentLetter != ' ' && currentLetter != '\n');

        if (word != " "  && !(word.find_first_of("0123456789") < word.length()))
        {
            //cout << word << endl;
            // insert(word); This will called the b


            if (errres == 0)
            {
                fputs(word.c_str(), result);
                //fprintf(result, "%s", word);
            }

        }
        word = "";
    }
    fclose(result);
}
```

}

Note:- The result is not formatted and I have written the code in hurry just to show.