# How can I increase terminal buffer size?

Tags: c++

Given below is just a simple program, to print 10,000 integers each in a separate line. But, the integers at the top disappear, as the lower statements are executed. Only 296 integers are displayed at once. How should I take care of this, and get all those 10,000 integers on the screen at once i.e. how can I increase terminal buffer size?

[Executable](http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/executable.exe)

```
     #include <iostream>
      main(){
    int i=10000;

    while (i){
    std::cout<<i<<"\n";
    i--;} 
int ch = std::cin.get();}
```

Compiler : CygWin GCC 4.9.2 IDE : Codeblocks.

Comment: Maybe you need to flush the output - easiest is to use `std::endl` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: Really? There is nothing (else) wrong with the posted code...

Comment: Are you sure your screen buffer is big enough to contain 10000 lines?

Comment: @fvu probably no.. And, I just want to know how to do that (if possible)...

Comment: @MatsPetersson the executable is [safe](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/5ec356ad15958d381ca5cb842c3ba2cb14ee1412b6d41d176facee682055cde9/analysis/1434300276/) you may run it.

Comment: No, Windows executables won't execute on my machine, and as others have already explained, the problem is really that you don't have enough scroll-back buffer to SEE the first output. That's not a C++ programming problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FILE\* in C++ not reading entire file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116130/file-in-c-not-reading-entire-file)

Comment: @StilesCrisis  that question talks about reading from a file, and this talks about output. So, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Both problems are the same. The reading-from-file is a red herring. Both issues are  actually"my program does [xyz] and I only see the last 300 lines of output."

Answer (score 3):

Actually all integers are correctly displayed. You can verify it by redirecting the program output to a file:

```
$ ./yourprogram >yourfile.txt
```

and then showing the first few lines of the output file:

```
$ head yourfile.txt
10000
9999
9998
9997
9996
9995
9994
9993
9992
9991
```

The problem you report is caused by a **limited terminal buffer size**.

Comment: "How should I take care of this, and get all those 10,000 integers on the screen at once?" . Can I increase this buffer size anyway?

Comment: Well, the purpose is not clear. Anyway, what about showing more numbers on each line?

Comment: Okay, this has no purpose and basically I am asking for increasing my knowledge. I just want to know if I can increase the buffer size

Comment: Usually it's configurable. Look for your terminal program's options.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/378313/windows-command-prompt-how-do-i-increase-my-buffer